# Auto detect browser language and start site accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, local, multilingual

I have a question. More precisely, I am writing here because I have no idea. How can I automatically detect the browser language and start the site in that language according to the url section with javascript. I searched many articles but could not find anything.
Let me give an example. My browser language is English and the English url on my site is (?Language=en) ... So I want to set the first site opening according to the browser language. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't, it's very often a poor UX. Offer a drop-down and let the visitor to choose the language.

Comment: Or alternatively use the `Accept-Language` header which is sent in every request using the language the user selects in their browser settings. Then you don't need to ask, and don't have to worry about storing the language in the session/URL

Comment: @Teemu Absolutely I agree. But unfortunately the customer wants that